# How to write a foreach-like macro to visit all nodes of a graph

Tags: c, macros, foreach, c99, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a graph of the following nodes:

```
typedef struct node node_t;
struct node {
    size_t adjacent_node_count;
    node_t **adjacent_nodes;
    void* data;
};
```

The graph is represented as a pointer to one of these nodes (that is, I dont have a single list of all nodes, but every node is guaranteed to be reachable from this 'root' one).

Now, I need to visit every node in this graph and apply some function to `data` in each of them only once. I suppose the simplest way to do this would be DFS.

Let us add some fileds to `node` to simplify implementation

```
typedef struct node node_t;
struct node {
    size_t adjacent_node_count;
    node_t **adjacent_nodes;
    void* data;
    node_t *dfs_stack_next;
    bool dfs_visited;
};
```

And the traversal itself is

```
void dfs(node_t *root, void* context, void (*function)(void* context, void* data)) {
    node_t *stack_top = root;
    while (stack_top != NULL) {
        node_t *current_node = stack_top;
        stack_top = stack_top->dfs_stack_next;
        if (!current_node->dfs_visited) {
            current_node->dfs_visited = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < current_node->adjacent_node_count; ++i) {
                node_t *adjacent_node = current_node->adjacent_nodes[i];
                adjacent_node->dfs_stack_next = stack_top;
                stack_top = adjacent_node;
            }
            function(context, current_node->data);
        }
    }
}
```

That was failry simple. However writing function and wrapping local context in structs gets painful fast, so I want to wrap this in a `foreach`-like macro:

```
for_each_node(n, root) {
   // do stuff with n->data
}
```

I got to getting top node from stack in a loop part

```
#define for_each_node(current_node, root) \
    for (state_t *current_node, *stack_top = root; \
         stack_top \
             ? (current_node = stack_top, stack_top = stack_top->dfs_stack_next, stack_top) \ 
             : stack_top; \
    ) /* ??? */
```

And now I am stuck. I realize that it is fairly simple to write a two part macro, like

```
for_each_node_begin(n, root)
    // do stuff with n->data
for_each_node_end(n, root)
```

that will simply split `dfs` in two on line with `function` call, I however find that rather ugly.

So, how do I go about implementing `for_each_node`? Is it at all possible? It doesn't need to be DFS, any order is fine, as long as `data` is processed once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some syntactic sugar to just prefix a block with a macro and that avoids you to have an "end" macro, this can be done systematically by using "dummy" `for`-loops that are guaranteed to be executed exactly once. *Writing* such things is a bit nasty, but to my experience it makes code that *uses* it much easier to grasp.

[P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) has a lot helper macros that would ease programming of such macros.  [`P99_GUARDED_BLOCK`](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__blocks.html) seems to be adapted to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is writing a function called `next_node`. A function that receives a node and returns the next node using dfs/bfs/whatever.

The macro will be:

```
for_each_node(n, root) \
    for (struct node* n = root; n != NULL; n = next_node(n) )
```

Note that a node must point to its parent and children for this to work. Also assumes the graph is a DAG. Non-directed graphs with circles need a different treatment.